# Export and Import Categories and Products

Tags: category, import, products, export

Is there a solution to export all the products and categories from a store and import them to a empty store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will import your products and categories. Note that you'll need to spend some time studying the fields and what values they take. Unfortunately, this is as simple as it gets for what you want to do.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-bulk-product-import-export-with-tier-pricing-product-custom-options-configurable-products-bundle-products-grouped-products-downloadable.html